# ODBC can't filter data with parameter

Tags: php, android, sql-server, parameters, odbc

I use ODBC for connect my Ms SQL Server database with My Android App via web service.
I try to get data using PHP Script, its run smoothly to get all data from my Ms SQL Server database. But when I try to get some data using 'WHERE' clause in my php script and add parameter in my query I got error. Here is my php script:

```
<?php
$dsn="myDSN";
$username="myUSername";
$password="myPassword";

$barcode = $_GET['barcode'];

$koneksi = odbc_connect($dsn,$username,$password);

$sql = "select Barcode_ID, WO, ProductCategory, SubProductName, OrderType from T_MAIN 
    where Barcode_ID = $barcode";

$respon = array();

$tbl_main = odbc_exec($koneksi, $sql);

if (odbc_num_rows($tbl_main) > 0) {
    $respon["data_main"] = array();

    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($tbl_main)) {
        $data_main = array();
        $data_main["barcodeID"] = $row["Barcode_ID"];
        $data_main["wo"] = $row["WO"];
        $data_main["product"] = $row["ProductCategory"];
        $data_main["subProduct"] = $row["SubProductName"];
        $data_main["ordertype"] = $row["OrderType"];

        array_push($respon["data_main"], $data_main);
    }
    $respon["sukses"] = 1;
    $respon["pesan"] = "Success!";

    echo json_encode($respon);
} else {
    $respon["gagal"] = 0;
    $respon["pesan"] = "Failed!";

    echo json_encode($respon);
}
odbc_close($koneksi);
?>
```

I run it in my browser and I get this errors:

```
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error, SQL state 07001 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\myscripts\get_data_main.php on line 15

Warning: odbc_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\myscript\get_data_main.php on line 19 {"gagal":0,"pesan":"Gagal Mengakses Database!"}
```

Can somebody help me solve this problem?
Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You need to scape string characters on your sql: `where Barcode_ID = '$barcode' `

Comment: I've already try that, but not work, because Bacode_ID is integer

Answer (score 0):

Use a parametrised query e.g.,  "select Barcode_ID, WO, ProductCategory, SubProductName, OrderType from T_MAIN where Barcode_ID = ?" then pass $barcode to the execute method.

Comment: +1 on parameterized query. @theochandra consider using PDO ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of `odbc_*` for a more OOP aproach

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your suggestions. I've already solved the problem. The warning show 'SQL state 07001 in SQLExecDirect', when I search it I get it 'Wrong number parameters'. So I try this code: 
        $sql = "select Barcode_ID, WO, ProductCategory, SubProductName, OrderType from T_MAIN where Barcode_ID = '".(int)$barcode."'";
and its works perfectly.